# Find the minimum of $P=\frac{1}{1+a}+ \frac{1}{1+ab} + \frac{1}{3+abc} $

Tags: inequality, optimization, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $a,b,c$ be nonnegative real numbers such that $a+b+c=3$. Find the minimum of
$$P=\dfrac{1}{1+a}+ \dfrac{1}{1+ab} + \dfrac{1}{3+abc}. $$

My attempt: 
I can prove that $\frac{1}{1+t}\geq \frac{5}{9}-\frac{1}{9}t$ and $\frac{1}{3+t}\geq \frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{9}t$. Now we obtain that
$$P\geq\dfrac{13}{9}-\dfrac{1}{9}\left(a+ab+abc\right)$$
I know the equality holds if $a=2, b =1,c=0$ but now I have no idea to use the assumption of the sum. Help me a hand please. Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried Lagrange multiplier?

Comment: @MathFail I want to use high school knowledge (without Lagrange)

Comment: @Chivul FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%2Ba%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%2Bab%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B3%2Babc%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24a%2Bb%2Bc%3D3%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aminimum&p=3), there's [Post #$474$](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1064117p8919575) of the AoPS thread [Inequalities from China](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1064117p8895361). It's listed as being #$160$, with this problem asking to show $P \ge 1$. However, there doesn't appear to be any solution within that thread.

Comment: Now it is enough to show $a+ab+abc\leq 4$ which looks simpler than $\frac{1}{1+a}+\frac1{1+ab}+\frac1{3+abc}\geq 1$.

Comment: $a+ab+abc=-a(b^2+(a-4)b-1)=-a\left(\left(b+\frac{a-4}{2}\right)^2-1-\frac{(a-4)^2}{4}\right)\leq a\left(1+\frac{(a-4)^2}{4}\right)$

Comment: $a\left(1+\frac{(a-4)^2}{4}\right)=4-\frac{(4-a)(a-2)^2}{4}\leq 4$ at $0\leq a \leq 3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Proceeding along your attempt*:

Using $\frac{1}{1+u} \ge 1 - u$ for all $u > -1$,
we have
$$\frac{1}{1+a} = \frac{1}{3 + (a - 2)} 
= \frac13 \cdot \frac{1}{1 + (a-2)/3}\ge 
\frac13(1 - (a-2)/3),$$
and
$$\frac{1}{1 + ab}
= \frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{1 + (ab-2)/3 }
\ge \frac13\cdot (1 - (ab-2)/3)$$
and
$$\frac{1}{3+abc}= \frac13 \cdot \frac{1}{1 + abc/3} \ge \frac13 \cdot (1 - abc/3).$$

Adding them up, we have
\begin{align*}
 P &\ge \frac{13}{9} - \frac19 a - \frac19 ab - \frac19 abc\\[6pt]
 &= \frac{13}{9} - \frac19 a - \frac19 a
 \cdot b \cdot (1 + c)\\[6pt]
 &\ge \frac{13}{9} - \frac19 a - \frac19 a
 \cdot \frac{(b + 1 + c)^2}{4}\\[6pt]
 &= \frac{13}{9} - \frac19 a - \frac19 a
 \cdot \frac{(4 - a)^2}{4}\\
 &= 1 + \frac{1}{36}(4 - a)(a - 2)^2 \\
 &\ge 1
\end{align*}
with equality if $a = 2, b = 1, c= 0$,
where we use $uv \le (u + v)^2/4$
to obtain $b(1 + c) \le (b + 1 + c)^2/4$.

Thus, the minimum is $1$ when $a = 2, b = 1, c=0$.

Comment: @Chivul You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

For $a=2$, $b=1$ and $c=0$ we obtain: $P=1$.

We'll prove that it's a minimal value.

Indeed, by C-S and AM-GM we obtain:
$$P-1=\frac{1}{1+a}+\frac{1^2}{1+ab}+\frac{1^2}{3+abc}-1\geq\frac{1}{1+a}+\frac{4}{4+ab+abc}-1=$$
$$\frac{1}{1+a}-\frac{ab+abc}{4+ab+abc}=\frac{4-a^2b(1+c)}{(1+a)(4+ab+abc)}=$$
$$=\frac{4\left(1-\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2b(1+c)\right)}{(1+a)(4+ab+abc)}\geq\frac{4\left(1-\left(\frac{\frac{a}{2}+\frac{a}{2}+b+1+c}{4}\right)^4\right)}{(1+a)(4+ab+abc)}=0.$$

Comment: Thank you. This helps me

Answer (score 1):

My try was the following. It is different than OP's way. Sorry about that.

By $AM$-$HM$ inequality we have $P\geq\frac{9}{5+a+ab+abc}$. For $P\geq 1$, it is enough to show that $a+ab+abc\leq 4$ under the condition $a+b+c=3$, $a,b,c\geq 0$ or equivalently $f(x,y)=x(1+4y-xy-y^2)\leq 4$ on the closed triangle $x+y\leq3$, $x,y\geq 0$.

Boundry: $\bullet$ If $x=0\implies f(0,y)=0.$ So, $\color{purple}{\max=0}$. $\bullet$ If $y=0\implies f(x,0)=x$, $0\leq x\leq 3$. So, $\color{red}{\max=3}.$ $\bullet$ If $x+y=3\implies f(x,3-x)=4x-x^2$, $0\leq x\leq 3$. It is left to the reader to show that $\color{blue}{\max=4}$ at $x=2$.

Interior:
$f_y=0\implies x(4-x-2y)=0\implies x+2y=4$. So, it is enough to consider $g(y)=f(4-2y,y)=(4-2y)(1+y^2)$ where $1<y<2$. What do you think? Must I have include $f_x=0$ in my analysis? Now, it is left to the reader to show that, in this case, [no maximum](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=optimize%20%284-2y%29%281%2By%5E2%29%20on%201%3Cy%3C2) can be found.

Conclusion: $\color{blue}{\max{f}=4}$. So, $P\geq 1$. Finally for $a=2,b=1,c=0$ we have $P=1$. So, $\min{P}=1.$

Answer (score 0):

By HM-AM we have

$$\frac 3 P \le \frac{5+a+ab+abc}{3} \implies P\ge \frac 9{5+a+ab+abc}$$

and we can conclude using the fine method suggested in the comments by [Ivan Kaznacheyeu](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/955514/ivan-kaznacheyeu) to show that $a+ab+abc \le 4 \implies P\ge 1$.

---

As an alternative for the second part by $b=x$ and $c=y$ we have

$$f(x,y)=a+ab+abc=(3-x-y)(1+x+xy)\ge 0$$

with $f(x,y)=0$ on the boundary and

- $f_x  =-2 x (y + 1) - y^2 + 2 y + 2=0$
- $f_y = -x^2 - 2 x (y - 1) - 1=0 \implies (x-1)^2+2xy=0$

which leads to $P=(1,0) \implies f(1,0)=4$ and by the Hessian

$$H(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}
-2y-2&-2x-2y+2\\
-2x-2y+2&2x
\end{pmatrix} \\ \implies H(1,0)=\begin{pmatrix}
-2&0\\
0&2
\end{pmatrix} \implies \det (H(1,0)=-4$$

which confirms that $4$ is a maximum value for the function.

---

As another alternative for the second part, for the quantity $Q= a+ab+abc$ we have to consider the following cases

- $a = 0 \implies Q=a+ab+abc =0$
- $a \neq 0 \land b=0 \implies Q=a \implies 0<Q\le 3$
- $ab \neq 0 \land c=0 \implies Q=a+ab=a(4-a) \implies 0<Q\le 4$ attained at $a=2$
- $0<abc =k\le 1\implies Q(k)=a+\frac kc+k \implies Q'(k)=\frac1c +1 \neq 0\implies 3\le Q(k)<4 $

Comment: How about $a=x$ and $b=y$?

Comment: We don’t need to evaluate this case. We have plugged all the necessary conditions in $f(x,y)$ which corresponds exactly to the given expression $a+ab+abc$ with $a+b+c=3$.

Comment: @BobDobbs I mean that, with these assumptions we obtain $g(x,y)=x+xy+xy(3-x-y)$ which has maximum value $4$ at $(2,1)$, exactly the same solution.

Comment: @BobDobbs Do you think that something is wrong in this solution?

Comment: You enriched your solution by logical statements. You also praised gerat names like Ivan, Hessian, user. Not bad, @user.